# "bundle exec spring binstub -all" fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring, bundler

When I make a new rails project:

```
rails new test_app
```

it fails with the following:

```
run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
bundler: failed to load command: spring (/Users/npresco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/spring)
LoadError: cannot load such file -- spring-commands-rspec
  /Users/npresco/.spring.rb:1:in `require'
  /Users/npresco/.spring.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/npresco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/commands.rb:29:in `require'
  /Users/npresco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/commands.rb:29:in `<module:Spring>'
  /Users/npresco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/commands.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/npresco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/binstub.rb:138:in `require'
  /Users/npresco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/binstub.rb:138:in `call'
  /Users/npresco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
  /Users/npresco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/npresco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/spring:23:in `load'
  /Users/npresco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/spring:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

I am using:
rbenv 1.1.1
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-darwin16]
rails 5.1.4
bundler 1.16.1

I suspect there is something going on with bundler but I am not sure what. I am able to run `spring  binstubs --all` inside the project directory but not `bundle exec spring binstubs --all`

Top of `bundle env`

```
Bundler       1.16.1
  Platforms   ruby, x86_64-darwin-16
Ruby          2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-darwin16]
  Full Path   /Users/npresco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/ruby
  Config Dir  /Users/npresco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/etc
RubyGems      2.7.3
  Gem Home    /Users/npresco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  Gem Path    /Users/npresco/.gem/ruby/2.5.0:/Users/npresco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  User Path   /Users/npresco/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  Bin Dir     /Users/npresco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin
Tools
  Git         2.11.0 (Apple Git-81)
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       rbenv 1.1.1

  chruby      not install
```

Comment: spring already running?  `ps aux | grep spring`.  If so, can you `spring stop` and try again?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I am baffled. I gone as far as uninstalled rbenv and reinstalled it and the latest ruby and rails and still get the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this, just replace `bundle` to `bundler`

```
$ gem install bundler
$ bundler exec spring binstub --all
```